# Is this a correct child spec ?

Tags: erlang

I notice there is the code as follows in cowboy https://github.com/extend/cowboy

```
supervisor:start_child(cowboy_sup, child_spec(Ref, NbAcceptors,
    Transport, TransOpts, Protocol, ProtoOpts)).

child_spec(Ref, NbAcceptors, Transport, TransOpts, Protocol, ProtoOpts) ->  
{{cowboy_listener_sup, Ref}, {cowboy_listener_sup, start_link, [ NbAcceptors, Transport,
TransOpts, Protocol, ProtoOpts ]}, permanent, 5000, supervisor,[cowboy_listener_sup]}.
```

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2

I don't think it is correct child spec, what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify the correctness of a child spec by using the [supervisor:check_childspecs/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#check_childspecs-1) function.

And yes, that looks like a valid child spec:

```
child_spec() = 
    {Id :: child_id(),
     StartFunc :: mfargs(),
     Restart :: restart(),
     Shutdown :: shutdown(),
     Type :: worker(),
     Modules :: modules()}
```

Where:

```
Id -> {cowboy_listener_sup, Ref}
StartFunc -> {cowboy_listener_sup, start_link, [ ... ]}
Restart -> permanent
Shutdown -> 5000
Type -> supervisor
Modules -> [cowboy_listener_sup]
```

What's the doubt, exactly?

Comment: Thanks a lot , I think I've got it now.

Comment: One more question: do you think this is a valid child spec ?  ```{ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(ReqsSup, [ListenerPid, CSocket, Transport, Protocol, Opts])```

Comment: @Why No that is not a valid child spec, it must be a tuple of 6 elements as @Roberto showed. Unless the your supervisor is a `simple_one_for_one` when the "child spec" becomes a list of extra arguments to the start child call. But that is **ONLY** in the `simple_one_for_one` case.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a simple_one_for_one spec, it is hard for me to understand!